# How do you set the time and only the time in a calendar in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, hour, minute

Having the hours and minutes, is there any easier or better way to set it into a Calendar object than:

```
calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        hour, minute);
```

Comment: This troublesome class `Calendar` is now outmoded, supplanted by the modern java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/Calendarsetintfieldintvalue.htm):

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [set(int field, int value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-). The first parameter is the field number for HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND.

Answer (score 2):

In 2018 no one should use the `Calendar` class anymore. It it long outmoded, and `java.time` the modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with. Instead use, depending on you exact requirements, a `ZonedDateTime` or perhaps an `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. In either case, set the time of day this way:

```
dateTime = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(hour, minute));
```

**Link**: [Oracle Tutorial Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: *"In 2018 no one should use the `Calendar` class anymore"* - have you heard about Android ;)

Comment: Yes, I have an Android device, @KonradMorawski. I have also heard about [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/build.gradle), the backport of java.time to earlier Android versions. More in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Sadly, modern Java datetime API isn't available on Android out of the box as of now. The backport is a third party library, and as such it's arguably an overkill for apps that don't do that much of datetime-related computations. One thing for sure, the legacy API is plain ridiculous.

Comment: There’s room for improvement. The ThreeTen Backport was developed by the original developers of java.time, though the Android adaptation is probably made by a third party. java.time comes out of the box from API level 26 (that’s fairly new, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the great accepted answer by Xn0vv3r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460312/2359227), don't forget to set

`calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);`